# Añadir campo adicional a la autenticación de usuarios en Laravel

Tags: laravel, login

Tengo una aplicación de Laravel que estoy usando para probar la autenticación que se crea con `php artisan make:auth`. A la migration que crea los usuarios le he añadido un campo para indicar si el usuario está activo o no, así:

```
...
$table->char('activo', 1)->default('S');
...
```

Lo que pretendo es que cuando un usuario introduzca su login y password, si no está activo (campo `activo` con valor `N`, por ejemplo), no le deje acceder o que, incluso, le diga que no puede acceder por haber sido desactivado.

El problema es que, como los métodos están en un entramado tan rebuscado, en distintos traits, y de un método llama a otro, no logro localizar cual es el método que tengo que sobrescribir en el controlador ni, mucho menos, como hacerlo.

A ver si me podéis dar una pista. Yo he revisado los traits `AuthenticatesUsers.php` y `ThrottlesLogins.php`. En el primero he revisado el método `login()`, pero no se ve claro el proceso (o yo, al menos, no lo veo claro).

Podéis orientarme?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para añadir campos adicionales a la autenticación de Laravel, debe recurrir al método `credentials` del trait `AuthenticatesUsers`, como su `LoginController` usa dicho trait bastaría con "sobre escribirlo" en su Controlador

El valor de `$this->username()` retorna el campo por defecto con lo cuál hará el proceso de login. *(tambien puede sobreescribirse, el valor por defecto es email)*

**LoginController**

```
public function username()
{
    return 'username'; // or email
}


public function credentials(Request $request)
{
    $credenciales = $request->only($this->username(), 'password');
    //añadimos el valor de activo a S, para que sea correcto
    $credenciales = array_add($credenciales, 'activo', 'S');
    return $credenciales ;
}
```

Comment: Hola. Gracias por el ejemplo. El caso es que funciona, pero cuando un usuario tiene el campo activo en N te da el mismo mensaje de error que cuando tecleas un usuario que no existe. ¿Hay alguna forma de discriminar esto para poder informar al usuario de que está inactivado? Donde puedo documentarme más sobre este tema? Muchas gracias.

Comment: Tiene razón. Gracias.